# Bash backup checker

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to compare dates from a file and the current day.
The script should run every day and if the dates do not compare it should give a warning.

I made a test file with a 2015 date, but it keeps saying its "equal" to the current date.

```
#!/bin/bash

today= date +"%m-%d-%y"
filedate= date +"%m-%d-%y" -r fileName.txt

if [ $today == $filedate ];
then
echo $today;
echo $filedate;
echo 'Backup OK';
else
echo $today;
echo $filedate;
echo 'Backup ERROR';
fi
```

Comment: Using mm-dd-yy dates is never going to work properly.  Switch to properly machine (and human!) readable yyyy-mm-dd dates; you will thank yourself many times over.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the `date` output to the `today` and `filedate` variables using [command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html). And you'd better double quote your variables in your comparison test:

```
today=$(date +"%m-%d-%y")
filedate=$(date +"%m-%d-%y" -r fileName.txt)

echo $today
echo $filedate
if [ "$today" == "$filedate" ];
then
echo $today;
echo $filedate;
echo 'Backup OK';
else
echo $today;
echo $filedate;
echo 'Backup ERROR';
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

[find](http://ss64.com/bash/find.html) utility is your friend.

```
modified=$(find fileName.txt -mtime -1)
if [[ -n $modified ]]; then
    echo OK
else
    echo ERROR
fi
```

As a piece of advice you may have to read carefully what atime and ctime means to the system time.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
today=$(date +"%m-%d-%y")
filedate=$(date +"%m-%d-%y" -r fileName.txt)

echo $today
echo $filedate
if [ "$today" == "$filedate" ];
then
echo $today;
echo $filedate;
echo 'Backup OK';
else
echo $today;
echo $filedate;
echo 'Backup ERROR';
fi
```